# grep command giving error

Tags: grep

I am using grep to filter out the contents on some patterns(genes in my case).
For more info, here is the earlier link.

[Find pattern from one file listed in another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115262/find-pattern-from-one-file-listed-in-another/115263?noredirect=1#comment180266_115263)

My code(should work) but is not.

```
 grep -f file1 file2
```

Here is my subset of genes(file1):

```
C1QTNF3
C5orf22
C5orf28
C5orf34
C5orf38
C5orf42
C5orf49
C5orf51
C5orf64
C6
C7
C9
CAPSL
CARD6
CARTPT
CCDC125
CCDC152
CCL28
CCNB1
CCNO
CCT5
CD180
CDC20B
CDH10
CDH12
CDH18
CDH6
CDH9
CDK7
CENPH
CENPK
CKMT2
CLPTM1L
CMBL
CMYA5
COL4A3BP
CR749689
CRHBP
CRSP8P
CT49
CTNND2
CWC27
DAB2
DAP
DDX4
DEPDC1B
DHFR
DHX29
DIMT1
DMGDH
```

And below is my text file(file2) which is getting matched up, even though there is no gene UNC79 in file 1 as seen in SNPEFF_GENE_NAME=UNC79 show to be present in file2.

```
  AC=3;AF=0.016;AN=186;BaseQRankSum=0.075;DB;DP=292;Dels=0.00;FS=4.271;HaplotypeScore=0.0891;InbreedingCoeff=0.0225;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=0.011;MQ=59.18;MQ0=1;MQRankSum=0.969;QD=13.42;ReadPosRankSum=-0.373;SNPEFF_EFFECT=INTRON;SNPEFF_EXON_ID=23;SNPEFF_FUNCTIONAL_CLASS=NONE;SNPEFF_GENE_BIOTYPE=protein_coding;SNPEFF_GENE_NAME=UNC79;SNPEFF_IMPACT=MODIFIER;SNPEFF_TRANSCRIPT_ID=ENST00000256339;VQSLOD=9.31;culprit=DP
```

Hence, The output of grep is the whole text blob from file2.

Below is the complete row from the file, which gives issue.The second column is the gene name.
I don't have this gene in my file1. And so I don't want the output of this particular row. I have 1000 such rows of different genes, which need to be filtered out only for the genes that are in file1.

```
    intronic    UNC79   14  94062922    94062922    A   G   het 80.54   3   14  94062922    rs183710732 A   G   80.54   PASS    AC=3;AF=0.016;AN=186;BaseQRankSum=0.075;DB;DP=292;Dels=0.00;FS=4.271;HaplotypeScore=0.0891;InbreedingCoeff=0.0225;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=0.011;MQ=59.18;MQ0=1;MQRankSum=0.969;QD=13.42;ReadPosRankSum=-0.373;SNPEFF_EFFECT=INTRON;SNPEFF_EXON_ID=23;SNPEFF_FUNCTIONAL_CLASS=NONE;SNPEFF_GENE_BIOTYPE=protein_coding;SNPEFF_GENE_NAME=UNC79;SNPEFF_IMPACT=MODIFIER;SNPEFF_TRANSCRIPT_ID=ENST00000256339;VQSLOD=9.31;culprit=DP    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:1,2:3:33:39,0,33
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your gene names are always in the 2nd column of the file, you can use `awk` for this:

```
awk '
    {   ## while reading the first file, save name in the array a
        if(NR==FNR){a[$1]++;} 

        ## If this is the 2nd file
        else{
            ## print if the value of the second column is defined in the array 
            if($2 in a){print}
        }
    }' file1 file2
```

The same, condensed:

```
awk '{if(NR==FNR){a[$1]++;}else{if($2 in a){print}}}' file1 file2
```

more condensed:

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1]++}($2 in a){print}' file1 file2
```

and truly minimalist (in answer to @Awk):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]}$2 in a' file1 file2
```

Comment: +1 you can make even simpler using `next` and `a[$1]`, is just enough. `a[$1]++` holds count of occurrence of index that is `$1`

Comment: @Awk the `next` is irrelevant, I added a truly minimalist version for your pleasure :).

Comment: Isn't grep able to restrict it to only a particular column,instead of searching through whole file?I was just curious on this.I tried to find something but wasn't.

Comment: @Ron no, grep does not know about columns, it just sees a stream of bytes. Whenever you want to deal with columns, think awk.

Answer (score 7):

Your `file2` includes a substring that `grep` is matching with one of the lines from `file1`.

#### Example

[image: ss #1]

You can see it in the above screenshot, the text is highlighted in red by `grep`. Incidentally you might want to use the color highlighting feature too:

```
$ grep --color=auto -f file1 file2
```

#### But I want to match only whole words??

If you want `grep` to only return matches that are "whole words" you can include the `-w` switch. This will only return matches are whole word matches using the "words" from `file1`.

Here I've created another file (`file1a`) that does include the gene `UNC79`.

```
$ grep C7 file1 file1a
file1:C7
file1a:C7
file1a:UNC79
```

Here when I run the `grep -wf ...` command with the 2 index files (`file1` and `file1a`) you can see that we get no match for `file1` and a match with `file1a`.

[image: ss #2]

*excerpt from grep man page*

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.
          The test is that the matching substring must  either  be  at  the
          beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded by a non-word constituent
          character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or
          followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent
          characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
```

This trick works in @Ron's situation because his gene names are bordered by non-word characters (`=`) and they're terminated with (`;`). Otherwise this trick would not likely work.

Comment: I just want only the content if it matches exactly.e.g. if I had this gene name UNC79 in file1 ,then i want the whole content from file 2.

Comment: I tried " grep -F -f file1 file2" ,as -F is used for fixed strings to be matched.

Comment: @Ron - I think you're thinking about the `grep` feature in the wrong way. If you told grep to find strings that were present in `file1` how do you expect it to anchor the matches that it finds? Why would it not return C7 as a match but would return UNC79? What is achoring UNC79 that would keep it from not matching XXUNC79XX too?

Comment: @Ron - thinking of it another way, when `grep` encounters C7 in your current file, what is special about it that would make `grep` not return it as a match?

Comment: yes agreed ,I only want it to return "C7" if it exists individually as C7 itself and not somewhere in "UNC79"

Comment: @Ron - OK good, so what is special about C7 by itself? I don't understand the context of your output, otherwise I could be more direct 8-)

Comment: More precisely I have a couple of columns in my file2,There is one column only consisting of genes,other column has this text.So if I can only match a fixed pattern,as I said in my previous comment..will be solved

Comment: @Ron - all the results you're looking for should start with a equal sign (`=`) and end with a `;`, right?

Comment: @Ron - remember that `grep` is dumb, it doesn't understand context of a match unless you tell it to explicitly look for things.

Comment: I added more info.I hope it makes more clear to u.and the problem I am having

Comment: @Ron - a simple solution would be to include the `=` sign and `;` at the end of each gene name in `file1`.

Comment: @Ron - here's a way to do what you want. Use `grep -wf file1 file2`.

Comment: works on the subset now,trying on the bigger file.I have 200 files like these.I am hoping it will work.

Comment: @Ron - if the gene's are all bordered by `=` and `;` it should.

Comment: in the second column,they are not.I am banking on grep -wf to work.The problem is in the column with all the text,not all rows have gene names present.But the second column always has.So I will miss out on those rows if I used "gene; technique

Comment: @Ron - it will still work but for a different reason, the 2nd col. is bordered by spaces which are also non-word chars.

Comment: @Ron - I must say you have interesting problems 8-)

Comment: they become interesting only after they seem to be getting solved until then its like so weird.

Answer (score 1):

@ terdon You can make more simple

`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($2 in a)' fil1 file2`

**--edit---**

@terdon

+1 if always it's in 2nd column then fine, but still problem is after storing index in array that is `a[$1]` while reading  file1, it simply checks `$2 in a` of file1, this just kills some time also, here is example of getting unexpected result without `next`, please don't mind here I am not telling your answer is wrong, I am just trying to show you that it simply reads file even after its work already over that is storing index in array `a`.

```
$ cat f1
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 1
1 2
2 3
3 4

$ cat f2
NOTHING

# Bad result without next, still awk is reading f1, this kills time right ?
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]}$2 in a' f1 f2
4 1
1 2
2 3
3 4


# It gives nothing but it's right 
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$2 in a' f1 f2
```

Comment: Nice, +1 but as I said above, the next is not needed. Nor the parentheses if you want to get golfish :)

Comment: You're quite right, using next is safer, even though it's not needed in the specific case. Good catch.