# Using grep to omit values given in a text file

Tags: linux, grep

Omit.txt

```
001
006
008
0016
```

Filetogrepfrom.txt

```
001
006
007
008
0016
00546
008
0031
00
0021
0016
```

I want to do

```
cat filetogrepfrom.txt | grep -a 00 | grep -v {lines from omit.txt}
```

Comment: (1) Why do you bother grepping for `00`?  Every line in your sample file already begins with `00`, and, even if it didn’t, you’re just arbitrarily adding complexity to the question.  (2) Luckily your question was fairly easy to understand, and your example input files helped (thank you for including them).  But it’s customary, when asking a question like this, to include the corresponding *expected **output**.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find patterns from one file listed in another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115262/find-pattern-from-one-file-listed-in-another)

Comment: `grep -vf omit.txt file.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -a 00 Filetogrepfrom.txt | grep -vf omit.txt
```

> -f file, --file=file
>
> > Read one or more newline separated patterns from file.  Empty pattern lines match every input line.  Newlines are not considered part of a pattern.  If
> >                  file is empty, nothing is matched.

This should do what you want.

Note: `grep` can read from a file so there is no need for `cat`

Also your `grep -a 00` is unnecessary given your example as it will match all lines.  Additionally it seems unlikely that you will need `-a` for a `.txt` file but I have seen stranger things.

Comment: Yeah, those two files where given as pure examples to make myself clear, the actual file does need -a as there are some strange characters in there

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `grep -a 00` is extraneous, the following should work:
`grep -vf omit.txt Filetogrepfrom.txt`

WARNING:  Unless you're sure that the `Filetogrepfrom.txt` will never contain, for example, '0011', which the `omit.txt` would filter out with '001', you really ought to bound your "omit.txt" using something more like -- ex: omit.txt:
`^001$
^006$
^008$
^0016$`

Comment: You would use `-x` to do matching across complete lines, or `-w` to do word matching. Either of these would get around the issue of matching substrings in this case. (And you would use `-F` to do string comparisons).